# Interface Segregation avoiding recompilation in Java

Tags: java, api, interface, compilation

Interface Segregation principle aims to avoid creating useless dependencies between components by splitting groups of cohesive features through new smaller interfaces.

One important benefit of adhering to is the removal of unnecessary compilation time forced when components were tight coupled with unnecessary part of fat interfaces.

But I wonder whether that benefit really exists in **Java**...

Indeed, in Java, contrary to C++ world for instance, as long as one used method doesn't change its signature, client component can be left untouched even if dependent module(interfaces generally) has grown, avoiding the need to recompile this latter.

So, is the benefit of compilation coupling really significant (maybe even non-existent) in Java?

Comment: You are right, Java is much more ductile in the presence of dependency changes. This stems from the inherently looser coupling between class files.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the signatures and number of members of the entire interface, then yes - there is no need to re-compile as long as the interface is constant and the JVM/Java versions don't conflict.

If it is adding more methods to an interface, then no.  However, Ceylon - a new java-like language - is trying to do something similar through interfaces that partially implement and adapters: (bottom of page)
http://planet.jboss.org/post/new_approach_to_introduction

Comment: I also disagree, the Java Specification, chapter binary compatibilty says: "Adding new fields, methods, or constructors to an existing class or interface" doesn't break older components.      http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html